# How do I pass the Basic Authorization I get from the one-off Setup Thread Group to the main thread group

Tags: jmeter

I have only one user credentials and would like to simulate multiple users. I created a SetUp Thread Group to have HTTP Authorization manager and Beanshell Postprocessor (to carry forward the cookies to the main thread group which has a Beanshell PreProcessor to get this). But the first sampler in the main thread group is failing because the Authorization is not carried forward from Setup Thread group to the main thread. How do I get it to the main thread group?
[image]

Comment: Variables created via beanshell are local to a thread, you should try using **properties** which are common to all threads, and reference it using the [__P](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or [__property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) function

Answer (score 0):

1. A [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) is a [Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
2. [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header is not a Cookie

Therefore if you're copying only cookies it doesn't mean that the `Authorization` header is also copied.

HTTP Authorization Manager obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) so if you move it one level up (to be at the same level with Thread Groups) it will be applied to both Thread Groups and generate the proper Authorization header for all the HTTP Request samplers in its scope.

P.S. Using Beanshell is a some form of a performance anti-pattern, [since JMeter 3.1 users are advised to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

Comment: Thanks, both of you